# How do I remove contiguous sequences of almost identical records from database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database containing real-time stock quotes.

There is a Quotes table containing what you would expect-- a sequence number, ticker symbol, time, price, bid, bid size, ask, ask size, etc.

The sequence number corresponds to a message that was received containing data for a set of ticker symbols being tracked. A new message (with a new, incrementing sequence number) is received whenever anything changes for any of the symbols being tracked. The message contains data for all symbols (even for those where nothing changed).

When the data was put into the database, a record was inserted for every symbol in each message, even for symbols where nothing changed since the prior message. So a lot of records contain redundant information (only the sequence number changed) and I want to remove these redundant records.

This is not the same as removing all but one record from the entire database for a combination of identical columns (already answered). Rather, I want to compress each contiguous block of identical records (identical except for sequence number) into a single record. When finished, there may be duplicate records but with differing records between them.

My approach was to find contiguous ranges of records (for a ticker symbol) where everything is the same except the sequence number.

In the following sample data I simplify things by showing only Sequence, Symbol, and Price. The compound primary key would be Sequence+Symbol (each symbol appears only once in a message). I want to remove records where Price is the same as the prior record (for a given ticker symbol). For ticker X it means I want to remove the range [1, 6], and for ticker Y I want to remove the ranges [1, 2], [4, 5] and [7, 7]:

Before:

```
Sequence  Symbol  Price
   0        X      $10
   0        Y      $ 5
   1        X      $10
   1        Y      $ 5
   2        X      $10
   2        Y      $ 5
   3        X      $10
   3        Y      $ 6
   4        X      $10
   4        Y      $ 6
   5        X      $10
   5        Y      $ 6
   6        X      $10
   6        Y      $ 5
   7        X      $11
   7        Y      $ 5
```

After:

```
Sequence  Symbol  Price
   0        X      $10
   0        Y      $ 5
   3        Y      $ 6
   6        Y      $ 5
   7        X      $11
```

Note that (Y, $5) appears twice but with (Y, $6) between.

The following generates the ranges I need. The left outer join ensures I select the first group of records (where there is no earlier record that is different), and the BETWEEN is intended to reduce the number of records that need to be searched to find the next-earlier different record (the results are the same without the BETWEEN, but slower). I would need only to add something like "DELETE FROM Quotes WHERE Sequence BETWEEN StartOfRange AND EndOfRange".

```
SELECT
   GroupsOfIdenticalRecords.Symbol,
   MIN(GroupsOfIdenticalRecords.Sequence)+1 AS StartOfRange,
   MAX(GroupsOfIdenticalRecords.Sequence) AS EndOfRange
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      Q1.Symbol,
      Q1.Sequence,
      MAX(Q2.Sequence) AS ClosestEarlierDifferentRecord
   FROM
      Quotes AS Q1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Quotes AS Q2
   ON
          Q2.Sequence BETWEEN Q1.Sequence-100 AND Q1.Sequence-1
      AND Q2.Symbol=Q1.Symbol
      AND Q2.Price<>Q1.Price
   GROUP BY
      Q1.Sequence,
      Q1.Symbol
   ) AS GroupsOfIdenticalRecords
GROUP BY
   GroupsOfIdenticalRecords.Symbol,
   GroupsOfIdenticalRecords.ClosestEarlierDifferentRecord
```

The problem is that this is way too slow and runs out of memory (crashing SSMS- remarkably) for the 2+ million records in the database. Even if I change "-100" to "-2" it is still slow and runs out of memory. I expected the "ON" clause of the LEFT OUTER JOIN to limit the processing and memory usage (2 million iterations, processing about 100 records each, which should be tractable), but it seems like SQL Server may first be generating all combinations of the 2 instances of the table, Q1 and Q2 (about 4e12 combinations) before selecting based on the criteria specified in the ON clause.

If I run the query on a smaller subset of the data (for example, by using "(SELECT TOP 100000 FROM Quotes) AS Q1", and similar for Q2), it completes in a reasonable amount time. I was trying to figure out how to automatically run this 20 or so times using "WHERE Sequence BETWEEN 0 AND 99999", then "...BETWEEN 100000 AND 199999", etc. (actually I would use overlapping ranges such as [0,99999], [99900, 199999], etc. to remove ranges that span boundaries).

The following generates sets of ranges to split the data into 100000 record blocks ([0,99999], [100000, 199999], etc). But how do I apply the above query repeatedly (once for each range)? I keep getting stuck because you can't group these using "BETWEEN" without applying an aggregate function. So instead of selecting blocks of records, I only know how to get MIN(), MAX(), etc. (single values) which does not work with the above query (as Q1 and Q2). Is there a way to do this? Is there totally different (and better) approach to the problem?

```
SELECT
   CONVERT(INTEGER, Sequence / 100000)*100000 AS BlockStart,
   MIN(((1+CONVERT(INTEGER, Sequence / 100000))*100000)-1) AS BlockEnd
FROM
   Quotes
GROUP BY
   CONVERT(INTEGER, Sequence / 100000)*100000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a nice little trick.  The groups that you want can be defined as the difference between two sequences of numbers.  One is assigned for each symbol in order by sequence.  The other is assigned for each symbol and price.  This is what is looks like for your data:

```
Sequence  Symbol  Price    seq1    seq2   diff
   0        X      $10      1       1       0
   0        Y      $ 5      1       1       0
   1        X      $10      2       2       0
   1        Y      $ 5      2       2       0
   2        X      $10      3       3       0
   2        Y      $ 5      3       3       0
   3        X      $10      4       4       0
   3        Y      $ 6      4       1       3
   4        X      $10      5       5       0
   4        Y      $ 6      5       2       3
   5        X      $10      6       6       0
   5        Y      $ 6      6       3       3
   6        X      $10      7       7       0
   6        Y      $ 5      7       4       3
   7        X      $11      8       1       7
   7        Y      $ 5      8       5       3
```

You can stare at this and figure out that the combination of symbol, diff, and price define each group.

The following puts this into a SQL query to return the data you want:

```
select min(q.sequence) as sequence, symbol, price
from (select q.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by symbol order by sequence) -
              row_number() over (partition by symbol, price order by sequence)
             ) as grp
      from quotes q
     ) q
group by symbol, grp, price;
```

If you want to replace the data in the original table, I would suggest that you store the results of the query in a temporary table, truncate the original table, and then re-insert the values from the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I want to add some additional comments to complement the excellent answer by Gordon Linoff.

You're right. It is a nice little trick. I had to stare at it for a while to understand how it works. Here's my thoughts for the benefit of others.

The numbering by Sequence/Symbol (seq1) always increases, whereas the numbering by Symbol/Price (seq2) only increases sometimes (within each group, only when a record for Symbol contains the group's Price). Therefore seq1 either remains in lock step with seq2 (i.e., diff remains constant, until either Symbol or Price changes), or seq1 "runs away" from seq2 (while it is busy "counting" other Prices and other Symbols-- which increases the difference between seq1 and seq2 for a given Symbol and Price). Once seq2 falls behind, it can never "catch up" to seq1, so a given value of diff is never seen again once diff moves to the next larger value (for a given Price). By taking the minimum value within each Symbol/Price group, you get the first record in each contiguous block, which is exactly what I needed.

I don't use SQL a lot, so I wasn't familiar with the OVER clause. I just took it on faith that the first clause generates seq1 and the second generates seq2. I can kind of see how it works, but that's not the interesting part.

My data contained more than just Price. It was a simple thing to add the other fields (Bid, Ask, etc.) to the second OVER clause and the final GROUP BY:

```
row_number() over (partition by Symbol, Price, Bid, BidSize, Ask, AskSize, Change, Volume, DayLow, DayHigh, Time order by Sequence)

group by Symbol, grp, price, Bid, BidSize, Ask, AskSize, Change, Volume, DayLow, DayHigh, Time
```

Also, I was able to use use >MIN(...) and <=MAX(...) to define ranges of records to delete.